# Pass arguments list to sass mixin and compose one value from it

Tags: sass

Sry for confusing title, don't know how to write it in simple manor.

What I want is something like this:

```
.someClass {
  @include transition(color, background);
}
```

to be transpiled to:

```css
.someClass {
  transition: color 200ms ease-in-out, background 200ms ease-in-out;
}
```

I couldn't find this in documentation.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some ways of doing this, what you are looking for is a sass mixin.

Although it is a good solution for simple use cases, it's not always the easiest.

Here I leave one example. I hope it's useful:

```
@mixin transition($duration, $ease, $props){
  $value: '';
  @if(type-of($props)=='string'){
    $value: $props $duration $ease;
  }
  @if(type-of($props)=='list'){
    $i: 0;
    @each $prop in $props{
      $i: $i + 1;
      $value: #{$value} $prop $duration $ease if(length($props) == $i, unquote(''), unquote(','));
    }
  }
  transition: $value;
}

.someClass {
    @include transition(200ms, ease-in-out, $props: color background);
}
```